# AVPlayer starts playing audio from URL too long

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, audio-streaming

I have a problem:
AVPlayer in my app starts playing audio from URL too long. It takes 5-15 seconds.

More, it gives wrong (as I guess) waiting reason: "AVPlayerWaitingWithNoItemToPlayReason". 
Here is my start playing method:

```
private func setNewPlayerItem(with url: URL) {
    player.automaticallyWaitsToMinimizeStalling = false
    player.replaceCurrentItem(with: .init(url: url))

    player.play()
}
```

And here is my debug. Look at the time.

```
2019-05-31 16:40:06 +0000 player timeControlStatus 0 (paused)
2019-05-31 16:40:06 +0000 player status 0 (unknown)
2019-05-31 16:40:06 +0000 player currentItem nil
2019-05-31 16:40:15 +0000 player currentItem Optional(<AVPlayerItem: 0x600003a34fa0, asset = <AVURLAsset: 0x600003889a40, URL = *valid URL*>>)
2019-05-31 16:40:15 +0000 player currentItem status 0 (unknown)
2019-05-31 16:40:15 +0000 player timeControlStatus 2 (playing)
2019-05-31 16:40:22 +0000 player status 1 (readyToPlay)
2019-05-31 16:40:22 +0000 player timeControlStatus 1 (waitingToPlayAtSpecifiedRate)
2019-05-31 16:40:22 +0000 player timeControlStatus 2 (playing)
2019-05-31 16:40:23 +0000 player currentItem status 1 (readyToPlay)
```

As you can see, **.currentItem** exists, so waiting reason "AVPlayerWaitingWithNoItemToPlayReason" is wrong. But why **.timeControlStatus** changes to *"waitingToPlayAtSpecifiedRate"* after *"playing"*?

This solution also doesn't work for me:

```
player.playImmediately(atRate: 1.0)
```

It happens with each track, so the issue is not in track.

Please help!

Comment: Hello Andrey! Have you check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42094622/8558606) out? (if iOS 10+)

Comment: Hello @GuilhermeMatuella! Yeah, I've tried it, and it doesn't work for me (the result is the same)

Comment: @AndrewKrotov did you solve it?

Comment: @NataliyaLeLoup unfortunately, no. We have changed backend logic, but it's still not ideal

Comment: @AndrewKrotov nothing yet? I'm facing the same issues.

Comment: @VagnerMachado Unfortunately no. I changed two places after that, but as I see in this app, they still have this issue